# Test Amplify Cognito Auth.SignIn() with react testing library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, react-testing-library

I have react app that allows users to register and then login into my app (to Dashboard component) from the homepage. Now I want to test my app. First I want to test my login and logout.

My idea of how to test it is following:

1. render homepage with login form
2. fill in username and password and click the login button
3. check for some text in the Dashboard
4. find the logout button and click it
5. check if the homepage has been rendered

The problem comes with that the login is implemented with AWS Cognito User Pool and when Dashboard should rendered I am getting error `const { attributes: { email, profile } } = await Auth.currentUserInfo();` `attributes are undefined` from Dashboard component. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700025/testing-amplify-auth-with-jest-enzyme) answer but that doesn't work.

I also thought that I can eliminate that by calling Auth.SignIn() first, within the test but I am getting the error `Auth: Native crypto module could not be used to get a secure random number.` that is discussed [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4886). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve either issue. Can you fix my problems or suggest another better approach?

PS. I would like `await Auth.SignIn()` working since I would use it in my other tests in the Dashboard (I will render the Dashboard component and then send/receive some data from DB).
Btw. `Auth.SignIn()` function works just fine in react app.

```
test("sign out user", async () => {

    Amplify.configure(config);
    // await Auth.signIn(TEST_USERNAME, TEST_PASSWORD); // want this to work
    const history = useHistory();
    render(<Dashboard />);

    // sign out svg exists
    const logoutSvg = screen.getByTestId("logoutSvg");
    expect(logoutSvg).toBeInTheDocument();

    // click it
    await userEvent.click(logoutSvg);

    // wait for disaperance of the dashboard
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(logoutSvg).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    })
        
    // check if home page is shown
    expect(screen.getByText(/Homepage/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/Log in/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    // screen.debug();
})
```

PPS. What is the correct way to use `await waitFor(()=>{})`. My way doesn't work.

I will gladly answer any follow-up questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll want to mock the AWS Auth lib during your test. Does this help answer your question: [how to mock AWS library in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649891/how-to-mock-aws-library-in-jest)?